# How to pass a method reference to a covariant parameter

Tags: java, generics, lambda, covariance, method-reference

Given we have the following classes an methods:

```
class Fruit {}
class Orange extends Fruit {}

void process(Consumer<? extends Fruit> action) {}
void eatOnlyOranges(Orange evt) {}
```

---

This compiles without warning.

```
    Consumer<Orange> consumer = this::eatOnlyOranges;
    process(consumer);
```

---

I want to allow this, but it doesn't compile?

```
    process(this::eatOnlyOranges);
```

Can I change the signature of `process(Consumer<? extends Fruit> action)` to make it work?

NOTE: Please assume that the implementation of `process(..)` will check if the given `Consumer` can handle the given `Fruit`. This detail is not relevant for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @EmersonCod's answer, changing the method signature to

```
<T extends Fruit> void process(Consumer< T > action) {
    // ...
}
```

seems to do the job.

Comment: Strange that it works and  `Consumer<? extends Fruit>` not, seems to be a compiler bug.

Comment: It is a compiler bug, I filed an issue-> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198676

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast the `Consumer` to the certain type

```
process((Consumer<Orange>) this::eatOnlyOranges)
```

Comment: I want to avoid this, thats why I asked how to change the method signature.